# Not able to apply two functions to a React Component

Tags: reactjs

What am I doing wrong here when assigning these two functions

```
function onAdd(e){
    console.log('+++++++++++++');
  }
function onRemove(e){
    console.log('-------------');
  }
```

to a React Button Component (with two instances)

```
function onAdd(e){
    console.log('+++++++++++++');
  }
function onRemove(e){
    console.log('-------------');
  }
const Button = ({ text, styleClass, onAdd, onRemove }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={e => onAdd(e)}
      onClick={e => onRemove(e)}
      className={'btn ${styleClass}'}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
               <div>
                    <Button text="Add"  onClick = {(e) => this.props.onAdd(e)}/>
                    <Button text="Delete"  onClick = {(e) => this.props.onRemove(e)}/>
               </div>
, window.root);
```

I am getting `onRemove is not a function` erro on clicking on each of the buttons now

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
function onAdd(e){
    console.log('+++++++++++++');
  }
function onRemove(e){
    console.log('-------------');
  }
const Button = ({text, onClick }) => <button onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}>{text}</button>

ReactDOM.render(
   <div>
      <Button text='Add' onClick={onAdd}/>
      <Button text='Delete' onClick={onRemove}/>
   </div>,
   document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There a couple of things that probably aren't too clear for you, and those are basically messing everything up.

First, the `Button` component has two handlers for the `onClick` event, and that is not possible. You should have just a single handler, like this:

```
const Button = ({ text, styleClass, onClick }) => {
    return (
        <button
            type="button"
            onClick={ onClick }
            className={'btn ${styleClass}'}
        >
            { text }
        </button>
    );
};
```

Then, when you render it, you shouldn't use `this.props.onAdd` or `this.props.onRemove` because `this` hasn't any `props` property which hasn't any `onAdd` or `onRemove` properties.

You should then transform your render into something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Button text="Add" onClick={ onAdd } />
        <Button text="Delete" onClick={ onRemove } />
    </div>,
    window.root
)
```

Assumed that `window.root` represents a valid document element.

Comment: Thanks a lots 0xc14m1z, but I have a question for you. What if I have another event like `onToggle` event! how can I have two handlers for onClick and onToggle then?

Comment: It depends, what does the `onToggle` event should do?

Comment: let's  say it is suppose to change background color of the page by toggleing `.green` class

Comment: Than you need a "higher" behaviour. I mean, your `Button` component still have just the `onClick` event... what else can you do with a button :) ? What changes, is what you do at that `onClick` event. For instance, instead of logging something, you could change a state property which cause a rerender.